# Connecting Oracle 11g to Postgres via dblink

Tags: postgresql, oracle, dblink

I  have administrator access to our Oracle database , but was wondering if its possible to connect an Oracle 11g database to Postgres database and if so, what steps would I need to follow.

I've seen a few tutorials mention an ODBC driver that needs to be installed, but looks like this driver needs to be installed on the Oracle server itself?

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>Community Wiki answer collecting answers left in question comments</sub>*

---

[a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name):

The ODBC driver needs to be on the computer that connects to the Oracle server not on the Oracle server itself. Plus: you can't use dblink for this, Postgres' DBLink can only connect to other Postgres servers. But you can use a foreign data wrapper. You only need the Oracle client libraries (not the ODBC driver) on the Postgres server, nothing needs to be installed on the Oracle server.

If you don't have administrator access to the Oracle database nor can you change anything in Postgres, then there is nothing you can do. Oracle's DBLink can only connect to other Oracle servers. You could install Oracle's "Heterogeneous Services" to be able to connect through ODBC (the Postgres ODBC driver, not the Oracle one) but that again would require that you have admin access to the Oracle database.

You need install Oracle's "Heterogeneous Services" then install the ODBC driver for **Postgres**, not the one for Oracle.

---

[EdStevens](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/83595/edstevens):

It's more than just the ODBC driver.  You'll need to install the Oracle Transparent Gateway for ODBC.  The Oracle database sends a client request to the Oracle listener, that uses a gateway config file to further resolve the request to an ODBC DSN. The full instructions are pretty complex but I have [an article](http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-heterogeneous-communication/oracle-transparent-gateway/) outlining the pieces and their connections. That should give you a good overview and framework with which to understand the more detailed instructions.

You'll need both the Oracle gateway *and* the Postgres ODBC driver. The best link I could find was this:

[Where to download DG4ODBC from?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/953944?tstart=0)

Of course, when you get there, you'll want to adjust for your version.  For the ODBC driver, that would come from Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be done depends on where the connection initiative is done. If the initiative is done from the Oracle side, you could use dg4odbc and configure it with the odbc driver and connection details for the Postgress database.

dg4odbc sets up a special kind of listener process that you refer to using a regular tns alias. This listener process has to be on the same machine is the ODBC driver but does not necessarily have to be on the database server. Ofcourse, the datbase server has a listener process but nothing -well maybe licensing- does prevent you from setting up a dedicated listener for dg4odbc on a separate macine.

In your Oracle database you setup a database link that uses your tns alias that points to the special listener.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the ODBC driver needs to be installed in the Oracle server. For the Oracle 11g you will need the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver, since the DG4ODBC is 64-bit.